# Yii2 Encryption generates different encryption data

Tags: encryption, yii2

I am using encryptByKey() for SSN and Account Number encryption in Yii2. The problem is that it generates different encrypted data for the same Account Number when I try to re-generate it.

I can't match it in the database like the following:

```
Customers::findOne(['account_number'=> Yii::$app->getSecurity()->encryptByKey($account_number, "someKeyHere")]);
```

Is there any encryption method available to generate same encrypted data every time I encrypt it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Generally, that's the way encryption is supposed to work. It is sometimes called ["ciphertext indistinguishability."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) Yielding the same ciphertext every time a given plaintext is encrypted undermines security by allowing attackers to analyze collections of ciphertext for patterns.

In this case, it looks like you only store one instance of the encrypted account number; you could argue that because the "message" is never repeated, cipher text indistinguishability is moot. That could lead you to justify the use of ECB mode (if your API offered it) or a HMAC (message authentication code, offered by the [hashData()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#hashData()-detail) method) to compute a lookup key. If an attacker gets access to your database, there will only be one instance of each key, and nothing is revealed.

However, this is still insecure if an attacker can provide account numbers that your system encrypts. For example, an attacker could pose a legitimate user and provide a SSN during registration. If they choose a duplicate number, and then look in the database, their maliciously chosen encrypted value will match a legitimate record. Or, if the system rejects their account number because it is a duplicate, the attacker will know that it is a number in use by a legitimate user. This is called an [oracle attack.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_attack)

If you use an HMAC (or ECB mode encryption), you would have to design your application very carefully to prevent chosen plaintext and oracle attacks. And, candidly, if you are now encountering these ideas for the first time, there are probably many other gaps in your knowledge that will lead to easily exploited vulnerabilities in your application.